# How To Set pageProps Property In Next.js Page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Considering the code below in **.../pages/_app.js**, **Component** is the component exported from the current page.

So assuming you visit https://yourdomain.com/about, the exported component in ***.../pages/about.js*** will be the value of the **Component** in **.../pages/_app.js**

Now when you console log the pageProps, an empty object is displayed.

My question is how do you set the pageProps value in **.../pages/about.js** for example.

**.../pages/about.js**

```
const About = () => {
 return <p>About Page</p>
}

export default About
```

**.../pages/_app.js**

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How To Set pageProps Property In Next.js Page

When you fetch the data using `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` then you pass `props` ie may be the data from api call . Then you pass it via `props` to your `Page Component`. That props is  represented as `pageProps`  in `_app.js`.

In your code here you have not not used data fetching `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` and passed return value from function as `props`. So You are getting empty Object as `pageProps`

```
const About = () => {
 return <p>About Page</p>
}

export default About
```

Below`todos` is passed as props to `Page Component`. When you do `console.log(pageProps)` in `_app.js` then you will get `api call result as pageProps`

```
export default function IndexPage(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      Todos list
      <ul>
        {props.todos.map((todo) => (
          <li key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const todos = await fetch(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"
  ).then((response) => response.json());

  return {
    props: { todos }
  };
}
```

[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-data-fetching-forked-61tkb?file=/pages/index.js)